# RaycastHit returns no hit when objects swap positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving a row of boxes and want to create an infinite effect. Every last box will swap its position with the cloned block in the beginning (see image).

For Debug purposes I am using a boxcast as raycast for each box. It does not move like the boxes but stays like the first row (1.) in the picture.

The boxcast works fine until I change the 5th box position with the clone box and deactivate the clone box. My first boxcast hits no collider for 6-10 frames after positions have been swapped even though box 5 transform.position is exactly on the boxcast position.

I have tried updating Physics Transform before Boxcasting. Tried different Raycasts(Overlapbox, Ray,...).

[image: scenario]

```
    private void MoveRowOfBlocks(float m)
    {
//debug variable set true when setting box position to clone position
        bool exceed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < movingBlockRow.Length; i++)
        {
            GameBlock go = movingBlockRow[i].GetComponent<GameBlock>();
            // Block exceeds valid area -> Swap with clone block
            while (movingDir == Vector2.right && go.transformPositionCache.x + m > GameField.xFieldExtent_M - GameField.blockWidth / 2
               || movingDir == Vector2.left && go.transformPositionCache.x + m < -GameField.xFieldExtent_M + GameField.blockWidth / 2
               || movingDir == Vector2.up && go.transformPositionCache.y + m > GameField.yFieldExtent_M - GameField.blockWidth / 2
               || movingDir == Vector2.down && go.transformPositionCache.y + m < -GameField.yFieldExtent_M + GameField.blockWidth / 2)
            {
                exceed = true;
                go.transformPositionCache -= GameField.totalWidth * movingDir;
                //go.transform.position = go.transformPositionCache + (m * new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(movingDir.x), Mathf.Abs(movingDir.y)));
                blockExceedCount += movingSign;
                Debug.Log(go.name + " Exceeds field. Position from beginning. " + "New Position: " + go.transformPositionCache 
+ " movingDir: " + movingDir + " Frame: " + debugFrameCount);
                if (blockClone != null || clonedBlock != null)
                {
                    blockClone.SetActive(false);
                    blockClone = null;
                    clonedBlock = null;
                }
                cachedExceededBlock = go;
                debugCount++;
            }
            debugCount = 0;
            go.transform.position = go.transformPositionCache + (m * new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(movingDir.x),Mathf.Abs(movingDir.y))); 
            if (exceed) Debug.LogError(go.transform.position);
        }
        

        // Move Cloned Object
        if (blockClone != null)
        {
            Vector2 dest = (Vector2)clonedBlock.transform.position + (GameField.totalWidth * cloneMovingDir) * -1;
            blockClone.transform.position = dest;
        }
        if (exceed)
        {
            Physics.SyncTransforms();
            Debug.LogError(movingBlockRow[4].transform.position);
        }
// Using Boxcasts foreach init box position for debugging
        foreach (Vector3 v in gameField.gridPointsWorldPosition) // gridpointsworldposition is initial box position (1.)
        {
            RaycastHit2D rayHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(v, new Vector2(GameField.blockWidth/2, GameField.blockWidth/2), 0, Vector2.zero);
            if (rayHit.collider == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("NO BOX FOUND IN CELL " + v + " Box position: " + movingBlockRow[4].GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().transform.position 
                     + " Frame: " + debugFrameCount); // Rayhit.collider is null even though box position = v
            }
        }
        debugFrameCount++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a rigidbody to each box fixed my problem.

Edit: Well, it only works when I dont put the Boxcast check like shown above. It works when I put it in Update before the movingblocks method which is called on the next frame.

So by using Rigidbodys it still does not hit on the exact frame but on the next one! So I fixed my problem with a workaround by calling a Coroutine and waiting for one frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the object to act as if it doesnt have a Rigidbody, set the Rigidbody to static.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).